# Redirect to Multisite site 2 if site 1 has a setting

Tags: multisite, filters

On my Multisite, there is a custom setting that indicates whether the site is disabled. It uses `get_blog_option($id, 'deleted')` flag that is set if the blog is marked for deletion (essentially, the blog is 'inactive').

That flag doesn't seem to be used if you load that site. So I need to intercept the Site 2 load if that flag is set  (`if get_blog_option(2,'deleted') === '1'`), and `wp_redirect` to a specific page on Site 1.

I believe I can do this with the `wp_loaded` filter. But is that the  proper filter to use? I need the theme code to load (since the test will be in the Child Theme's `functions.php` file; I don't need it to be in a separate plugin), but the blog content needs to switch to Site 1.

It's not clear to me from the docs that using the `wp_loaded` filter is the proper spot to switch to Site 1. Is '`init`' filter better?

What sequence should I use to allow the 'test' in the Child Theme `functions.php` to switch to another blog if needed?

Related to this is that if you 'inactive' a blog (via the Sites screen), why does that blog still load on the front end?

**Added**

I think what I need is a filter just after the blog ID has been set. Been looking through the 'load' process, but it's a bit complex.

Comment: Isn't it better to just hook into something like `wp_update_site` and change `.htaccess` accordingly? Why go through WP for a redirect at all?

Comment: I think what I need is the hook that runs just after the subsite ID is available (via get_current_blog_id function). The site ID is used via get_site($id) to get options for that site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing a global functionality for your entire multisite/sub-sites like what you describe, you should implement this as mu-plugins instead adding the cuztomization inside a theme file, just create a file like in `wp-content/mu-plugins/GlobalConfig.php` which holds the customization you want and will take effect globally, unless you want this customization for only specific sub-site.

the `init` runs before the `wp_loaded`, but you can intercept the request at [plugins_loaded](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) hook since it runs even before `init`

e.i.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {

    //skip wp back-end request
    if ( is_admin() )
        return;
        
    $isDeleted = get_blog_option(get_current_blog_id(), 'deleted');
    
    if ( $isDeleted )
        exit( wp_redirect( 'https://site2.com/sub-page', 301 ) );
});
```